# Chrome address bar & tabs turn black

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 18.04, graphics, google-chrome

My machine has Ubuntu 18.04 installed.

I use Google Chrome and I often work with Jupyter Notebooks.

When I launch the browser everything seems to work fine. After some time (~ 1-2 hours) the address bar and the tabs part turn black as shown below.

[image]

Not happy.

---

Graphics Card: NVIDIA Quadro M4000

The problem persists both when I use the NVIDIA proprietary driver and when I use the open source X.Org X server driver.

Comment: Check if disabling chrome "hardware acceleration" in settings changes this behavior.

Comment: What would be the side effects?

Comment: @SanduUrsu It uses more CPU power.

Answer (score 5):

I have exactly the same issue with Chromium and Quadro M4000M (ThinkPad P70) on Arch Linux (xmonad, nouveau). So my conclusion is, that there is a bug in chromium that was introduced in the last year. Probably Quadro / M4000 related. It worked before with Nouveau and Nvidia driver.

I am not aware of any solution to fix it, but there are some workarounds:

- You can drag and drop the tabs to another browser window and recover them manually.
- You can use a browser plugin like OneTab to save and close all affected tabs. Then open a new window and restore all saved tabs (use mouse hover to find the OneTab button).
- Disabling hardware acceleration in chrome settings could work, but you will lose some rendering performance.

Check results of `chrome://gpu` - It reports some issues for my system, not sure if it is related.

Could be related to `GL ERROR :GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY : GLES2DecoderImpl::DoBindTexImage2DCHROMIUM: <- error from previous GL command`

**Update 1:** I have created a bug report here:
[Issue 893117](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=893117)

Answer (score 2):

It appears that there's an issue with the default display drivers on Ubuntu 18.04. I ran into the same issue ever since I installed (and reinstalled) Chrome and a possible work around is to use an alternative display driver.

*I followed instructions from this page: https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/install-nvidia-driver-ubuntu-18-04*

**To summarize:**

- Search for ***Software & Updates***:

[image: Software & Updates]

- Navigate to ***Additional Drivers*** (it might take a few seconds to load):

[image: Drivers]

- Select something ***other*** than the default *X.Org.X server*. This might require a reboot but since making the change I haven't had the Chrome issue happen again.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with nvidia driver version 450.66 & an Nvidia GTX 1660 Ti.  Try opening `chrome://settings` and disable "Use hardware accelleration when available", it worked for me.